# mmcqd hangs and burns the CPU on the embedded device

Tags: linux, embedded, sd-card

On my embedded system I'm writing an intensive video stream to SD. I don't mount partitions, just write to `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. After a while my writing process hangs. I get

```
[16952.240000] INFO: task vrec:1297 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

`[mmcqd]` eats 90% and dmesg shows me

```
[64142.350000] mmc0: starting CMD13 arg e6240000 flags 00000015
[64142.350000] mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000
[64142.350000] mmc0: starting CMD13 arg e6240000 flags 00000015
[64142.350000] mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000
[64142.350000] mmc0: starting CMD13 arg e6240000 flags 00000015
[64142.350000] mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000
[64142.350000] mmc0: starting CMD13 arg e6240000 flags 00000015
[64142.350000] mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000
[64142.350000] mmc0: starting CMD13 arg e6240000 flags 00000015
[64142.350000] mmc0: req done (CMD13): 0: 00000c00 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

After a card eject/inject all works fine. Please, help me to debug it.

Linux kernel: 2.6.28.9

Answer (score 5):

`mmcqd` is a kernel process responsible for the I/O queue. If you're getting high resource usage from this, that means your SD card is too slow for your video stream.

In cases like this, you really need a class 10 SD card or an UHS card designed for video streaming. The reason the system responds after an eject/insert is becuase the queue is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few refinements. The system works well for a few hours, fills a card a lot of times and then hangs. And after hang there is no other mmc commands in log except of `CMD13`, no writings. And yes, I'll check other cards.